# Pillow that has a zipper muktzeh on Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, muktzeh

If a pillow contains a zipper, would that pillow be muktzeh on Shabbos, and if not, would the zipper itself be muktzeh on Shabbos, even when it is attached to the pillow?

Comment: The basis of the question seems to be assuming that a zipper is Muktzeh. Just about every pair of men's pants and (as far as I know) most women's dresses have zippers, and I have never heard of any problem with wearing them. Can you clarify why you would think a zipper on a pillow would be problematic?

Comment: @Salmononius2 - a zipper not attached to anything is surely Muktza. And zipping up pillows is possibly not permissible, as we discussed here - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/88772/501

Comment: see here https://rabbikaganoff.com/%ef%bb%bfsewing-on-shabbos/

Answer (score 4):

As we already discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/88772/501), it's a debate among Poskim if a zipper meant to be zipped for long periods of time, like a pillow, can be zipped on Shabbat.

However, the pillow itself is the important part and the zipper is simply a minor detail, hence it wouldn't make the pillow muktza.

A zipper not attached to anything has no use on Shabbat and should probably be muktza.